# how can i host a website on my local ipv4?

Tags: web, localhost, port

I have a folder called "Site".
Inside the folder there is an HTML file called "index" and a JavaScript file called "script"
I have 2 computers connected to the local network.
I want when I go to the other computer and type in the browser the IP address of the first computer I will see the file "index"

I think I should put this file on port 80 or something like that

For hours I looked for a way to do it and could not find a solution. Thanks to the helpers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install a webserver on computer1. This webserver would have a port it can listen and a configuration for a default site.

If you just want to open a html-document, you can add a share on the "site"-folder and type in the Browser of pc2 something like \pc1\site\Index.html.